# How to apply tint color to NSButton (style Inline) cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbutton, tint

How to apply tint color to NSButton of style  `inline` and visual `bordered`
Below is block of code i am using

Round one is inline button
[image: round one is button]

After using the below code

[image]

```
InlineButton.wantsLayer = YES;
        InlineButton.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
```

how to change only tint of button

Any suggestion would be more helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The `isBordered` property of button is related with `bezelStyle` property. You can set different style to check the appearance.

And if you want button image have specific color. Try use the template image and `contentTintColor`.

```
let button = NSButton()
button.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.stopProgressFreestandingTemplateName)
button.image?.isTemplate = true
button.bezelStyle = .inline
button.isBordered = false
button.contentTintColor = NSColor.red
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Example (Swift):

```
/// The system window mockup
var layer = self.systemWindowMockupView.layer
layer?.cornerRadius = 6
layer?.backgroundColor = settings.windowBackgroundColor?.cgColor
layer?.masksToBounds = true. // <<<---- This is what you're looking for
```